# Laravel. Problema con las traducciones

Tags: laravel, json, i18n, internacionalización, traducción

Quiero traducir a español la vista de login, con los mensajes `E-mail address`, `Password`, `Remember me`, etc.
Según la documentación, dentro de `resources/lang/` tengo que crear un archivo llamado `es.json`. Esto funciona bien. Sin embargo, hay un problema. Según vaya creando vistas, este archivo irá creciendo, y puede llegar a ser realmente largo. Lo que quiero es ver como puedo fraccionar los textos en un archivo de traducciones para cada vista. He intentado todo lo que pone la documentación, y lo que he encontrado en Internet (qué es más de lo mismo), y no me funciona. En el momento en que pongo frases en otros archivos que no se llamen `es.json`, no hay forma de acceder a ellas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde yo se, Laravel no tiene ninguna opción para cargar sólo ciertos archivos para un determinado lenguaje. Es decir, una vez detectado el lenguaje, carga todos los archivos de dicho lenguaje (o de otra forma, de dicha carpeta). Así que si tu pregunta va relacionada hacía obtener una mejor performance, creo que de momento no hay solución.

Ahora, si tu pregunta va enfocada hacia "como fraccionar" un determinado archivo en varios para tenerlo todo más ordenado, es sencillo: sólo tienes que llamar a tus archivos de una determinada forma: users, products, etc. y al generar la traducción pasarle como parámetro la etiqueta precedida del archivo en cuestión donde ésta la misma. Es decir:

En el archivo "users":

```
'user' => 'Usuario',
'name' => 'Nombre',
```

Y para obtener la traducción en tu vista/controlador...

```
trans('users.user');
trans('users.name');
```